# Invalid schema detected - no type or db_type element Dreamfactory

Tags: mysql, api, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, postman

I'm using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com) and [dreamfactory](http://www.dreamfactory.com) and I get the following error message, when I send a post request to create a record in a table. I'm using MySQL as my database. I believe it could be because I haven't set up my foreign key relationships properly. How can I go about setting this up?

```
Invalid schema detected - no type or db_type element.
```

### Below is the request header

```
General 
----
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request
URL:http://localhost:8080/api/v2/MySQL/_schema/kartadb.country/1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 20 Oct 2015 08:17:33 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.29

Request Headers
----
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic dGV3b2Ryb3Mud3JAZ21haWwuY29tOg==
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:92
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Postman-Token:3f469a4f-f95a-eb1f-c5eb-8da94b110e47
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
X-DreamFactory-Api-Key:6498a8ad1beb9d84d63035c5d1120c007fad6de706734db9689f8996707e0f7d
X-DreamFactory-Session-Token:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjcsInVzZXJfaWQiOjcsImZvcmV2ZXIiOmZhbHNlLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MFwvYXBpXC92MlwvdXNlclwvc2Vzc2lvbiIsImlhdCI6IjE0NDUzMjY2OTQiLCJleHAiOiIxNDQ1MzMwMjk0IiwibmJmIjoiMTQ0NTMyNjY5NCIsImp0aSI6ImNlMDJiMWU1ZTRjZjc4MmZmYTYxZmYyZDM1MGNiODg2In0.F0UcNExumeAwLF-xM6SmgKktcPSprYrS7x95KFJmYI4
```

Comment: Can you show your post request?

Comment: Hey @flowit, I've edited the question with the post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention creating a "record" in a table. The /_schema resource is for creating table schema, not records. Use the /_table resource for creating records.

Comment: Thanks @Lee, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: For all who had problems with setting up their foreign key relationships, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-foreign-keys-tab.html is a great resource.